# Different types for `std::sort` comparator in C++

Tags: c++

When we provide a comparator function for `std::sort`, we use the following overload:

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

in which the comparator function for `std::sort` should have the following syntax:

```
bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
```

But as you can see `a` and `b` may have different types. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) says:

> The types `Type1` and `Type2` must be such that an object of type `RandomIt`
>   can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to both of them. ​

But I still cannot understand exactly how we can have 2 different types in a single array when we try to sort it.

Is it possible for someone to provide a small example with different types for `std::sort`'s comparator function?

Comment: For example, small integer types can be implicitly converted to larger integer types (like `short` or `int` to `long`). That means you could have a container of `short` values and a comparator taking one `int` and one `long` argument. I see no reason for this though.

Comment: I don't think you can have two types in a single array (without clever trick). The quote simply means `RandomIt::value_type` may be convertible to several other types.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Its not about what is stored in the array, only one type can ever be stored. It is about what the comparator function is. Take for example this:

```
struct Animal {};
struct Cat : Animal {};
struct Dog : Animal {};
struct Hound : Dog {};

bool cmp(const Animal &a, const Animal &b);
```

Even if you have a list of `Dog`s, `Cat`s or `Hound`s you can still sort them with the function `cmp` because they are all implicitly convertible. ie.

```
std::vector<Hound> hounds;
... // fill hounds
std::sort(hounds.begin(), hounds.end(), cmp);
```

And you can even imagine cases where `Type1` and `Type2` are not the same, eg.:

```
bool cmp(const Animal &a, const Dog &b);
etc ...
```

Although this would be exceedingly rare.

> The types Type1 **(Animal)** and Type2 **(Dog)** must be such that an object of type RandomIt **(Hound)** can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to both of them. ​**Which is true**.

The point is that a restriction on the types that a `cmp` function can take to the same, precludes generality. In some cases this is a good idea, but in this case it would be unreasonably strict and may force problems for edge case implementations. Furthermore, the `cmp` function used in`std::sort` is bound by the requirements set out for [*Compare*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) (probably for simplicity). *Compare requirements* are used for all sorts of other things, like `std::max`.

Comment: but still both arguments of comparator function is `Animal`. I want to see when we can have 2 different types in comparator function as standard.

Comment: @Afshin I have added an example of this.

Comment: @Afshin its not about restricting to the most typical use case only but to have maximum possible generality (allowing differnt types for the comparator) while still guaranteeing correctness (the types can be implicitly converted). It would be a major annoyance if you had a function that can compare the instances in the container, but you could not use it for sorting the container

Comment: Hm....This is true...But after a little thinking, I thought maybe this can be used for sorting in multiple-inherience. But maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: added a multiple inherience example to my port :)

Comment: I think this is a good answer, although the way you mentioned the possibility of `Type1` and `Type2` being different seems kind of arbitrary. I'd like to see it justified with an example in which it makes sense to have different types for the different arguments of the comparator, if one exists, or alternatively a statement that there's no good reason to do that (if that's what you think) would round out the answer nicely.

Comment: @DavidZ I can't really think of an exanmple where they should be different for `std::sort`, so I have said this would be exceedingly rare in the answer. Certainly there are arguments for other `std` algorithms using *Compare* (easy would be `std::max` on angles in radians and degrees for example). Can you think of one for `std::sort`?

Comment: Nah, I couldn't think of one either. I wouldn't be surprised if there's no good example for `std::sort()`, since any element of the list could appear on either side of the comparison operator. But I wasn't sure if there was something I'm missing. (Good point about `std::max()` by the way.)

Answer (score 13):

> But I still cannot get it exactly how we can have 2 different types in a single array when we try to sort it.

You can't have two different types in an array. The comparator doesn't suggest it's possible. It's specified like that simply because:

1. The code *can* be well formed when the types are not the same.
2. Demanding the same type is a restriction that serves little to no purpose.

So the specification offers a looser contract than is "obvious", in order to help our code be more flexible if needed. As a toy example, say we have this comparator laying around:

```
auto cmp(int a, long b) -> bool { return a < b; }
```

Why prevent us from using this perfectly legal (albeit silly) function to sort an array of integers?

Comment: I found it possible with multiple inheritance as I added in my post. if your array objects has multiple inheritance, you can compare 2 different types of parent in your comparator. But I agree it will be silly in normal conditions.

Comment: @Afshin - Yes, that's one example. The point I was trying to make is that even without an example in mind, the specification can be reasoned and defined loosely to allow for flexibility in general.

Comment: With the same reasoning, the return type doesn't have to be `bool`, just something contextually convertible to `bool` (cppreference is not obvious about this, it's hidden in the definition of Compare)

Comment: While I can see why there's no reason to prevent using this type of comparison function, it also seems pointless to use it. It's unpredictable whether any particular element of the sequence will be passed as `a` or `b` (the same element might serve different roles at different times during the sort).

Answer (score 7):

> But I still cannot get it exactly how we can have 2 different types in a single array when we try to sort it.

You can't.

But the requirements of *Compare* are not just for sorting arrays, or just for sorting at all!

They're for any time you want to compare one thing to another thing.

Is `minutes(42)` less than `hours(1)`? Yes! You may find useful a comparator for such occasions.

***Compare* is a more general concept that finds uses throughout the language.**

> Is ti possible that someone provide a small example with different types for std::sort's comparator function

Others have shown examples that indicate how silly you have to get to find a "useful" example to use against `std::sort` specifically.

But it's not "std::sort's comparator function". It's *a* comparator function, which you just so happen to be using with `std::sort`.

It's true that, when doing so, you probably want the particular comparator that you pick to accept operands of the same type.

Comment: it is true that comparator function does not belong to `sort`, but in other cases situation is much simpler. for example in case of `lower_bound` comparator takes 2 argument, one from type of iterator and other from type of key. I never had problem with it and I used it easily. but in case of `sort` it was somehow strange.

Comment: @Afshin Well if the comparator does not belong to `sort` then why is it strange?

Comment: Just because understanding in context of sort was strange. Anyway, my problem is solved now. thanks for your great reply.

Answer (score 4):

> But I still cannot get it exactly how we can have 2 different types in a single array

You cannot have two different types in a single array.

An array can have objects of only single type. But that single type must be implicitly convertible to both argument types of `cmp`.

> Is ti possible that someone provide a small example with different types for std::sort's comparator function?

Here you go:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 0};
auto cmp = [](const int &a, const long &b) {
    return a < b;
};
std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), cmp);
```

Note the two different arguments of `cmp`. This is just a minimal example, which is technically correct, but admittedly nonsensical. Frankly, I've never encountered a case where it would be useful to have different types for the arguments of a comparison function.

Answer (score 4):

The requirements for a *comparator* are far looser than you think:

1. It must accept two dereferenced iterators into the sequence as arguments.
   Using an implicit conversion-sequence is fine.
2. The return-value must be contextually-convertible to `bool`.
   An explicit conversion-operator works just fine.
3. It must be a copyable and nothrow-destructible complete type.
4. It must not modify the arguments, so it doesn't interfere with the calling algorithm.
   That does not in any way imply the use of constant references if references are used at all.
5. It must induce a full weak order (cmp(a, b) implies !cmp(b, a), cmp(a, b) && cmp(b, c) implies cmp(a, c)).

So, a valid but fairly useless comparator would be:

```
template <class... X>
auto useless(X&&...) { return nullptr; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The type requirements on `Compare` are not saying much about the elements of the sequence you are sorting, but instead they are allowing all `comp`s for which

```
if (comp(*first, *other))
```

is valid.

*Most of the time*, `Type1` will be equal to `Type2`, but they are not *required* to be equal.